# How to handle pop up or notification in Macbook

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get text of pop up using selenium webdriver.

1. Open URL https://ads.google.com/intl/en_IN/home/pricing/
2. Click on link 1800-419-6346* ( I am having xpath for this `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='eto eto-number']")).click();`)
3. Now after click on above link , Here one Pop up is getting displayed which is showing message as “Open FaceTime?” .

How we can handle such type of pop up , I just know “Open FaceTime” is application which run on MacBook .
I tried to handle with alert class but it did not work.

```
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
System.out.println(alert.getText());
```

after running code ,I am getting message "no such alert"

Please note on Windows machine that popup will not be displayed, it is specific to Macbook.

My Code as below :-

```java
public class Session1Mac {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("enter into first method");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/aturkar/eclipse-workspace/AutomateBSQATaskonMac/Lib/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(); // launch chrome
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
        driver.get("https:/ads.google.com/intl/en_IN/home/pricing/");
        Thread.sleep(20);
    }

    @Test()
    public void VerifyRedirectingToDialer() throws InterruptedException, Exception{
        //  driver.findElement(By.linkText("800-419-6346*")).click();  
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='eto eto-number']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Element got clicked");
        Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
        System.out.println(alert.getText());
    }
}
```

Error on Console:- 
Actual:-

> org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert

Expected:-I Want to get text of "Pop-up", if yes then how we can get it ? could you please help me with this.